# How to give the hint of edittextbox of dialog which is created by code in android

Tags: android

I am creating a dialog box where there is a edit box I want to set the hint of editbox how can I do it.

please help me
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this works but might help you,

You could have initialized your Dialog with something like this,

```
         Dialog dialog = null;
```

And now to Initialize your EditText you should use something like this,

```
      edittext = (EditText) dialog. findViewById(R.id.editbox);
```

Now use the below method. It should do the trick,

```
            edittext.setHint("Hint");
```

Comment: I have post another question plz check it.

Answer (score 2):

Every EditText is also TextView and the TextView defines a method setHint():

```
final void setHint(int resid)
```

Doesn't this work?

**EDIT** Btw by edit box you mean EditText right?

Answer (score 0):

The same you can provide in the XML file also by adding :

```
android:hint="Text For Hint"
```

tag.

For dynamically adding it (in your code and not in XML), Boris & Androi have aldready mentioned it, so wont repeat it.

If you wont be changing once set, then I guess adding in XML is preferred rather than in code.